# One hour expiration time for Github APP Installation token problem

Tags: python, pygithub, github-api-v3

I'm collecting data from several repositories (around 10k) from my organization for a AI search engine.
I have written a python script (using PyGithub lib) to fetch the data, including a rate limit access that checks if the run time is close to 60 minutes (the expiration time for a Github APP installation token), puts the script to sleep so it can generate a new token and proceed.

This is the script:

```
def main():
    token = get_token()
    g = Github(token)
    org = 'XYZ'
    count = 0
    data = []
    start_time = time.time()
    rate = g.get_rate_limit()
    print(f"Initiating at: \n\
            Reset time: {rate.raw_data['core']['reset']}\n\
            Remaining requests: {rate.raw_data['core']['remaining']}")

    for repo in g.get_organization(org).get_repos():
        
        # Check the rate limit and regenerate token if needed
        g = check_rate_limit(rate,start_time)

        # If the rate was regenerated, update the rate object
        if g:
            rate = g.get_rate_limit()

        # Collect data for the repo
        collect_data_for_repo(data,repo)
        

        count += 1
        print(rate.raw_data['core']['remaining'])
        print(f'{repo.full_name}, {count}\n--------------------------------')
        print(f"{g.get_rate_limit()}")

    columns = ['Repository Name', 'Link', 'Readme Content', 'Comments', 'Languages', 'Topics']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    rate_end_printing = g.get_rate_limit()
    print(f"Rate limit remaining: {rate_end_printing.raw_data['core']['remaining']}")
    #print(rate.raw_data['core']['remaining'])
    #print(f'{repo.full_name}, {count}')
    return df
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and this is the check_rate_limit func:

```
def check_rate_limit(rate,start_time):
  
  if time.time() > rate.raw_data['core']['reset'] - 60:
    sleep_time = 120
    print(f'Putting to sleep for {sleep_time} seconds (runtine over 60 minutes)')
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    token = get_token()
    print(f'Token regenerated at {datetime.datetime.now()}')
    return Github(token)
```

It collects data, reaches the time limit, generates a new token and when it continues I still get this error:

BadCredentialsException: 401 {"message": "Bad credentials", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"}

Any ideas on dealing with this time expiration limit when dealing with Github APP tokens?